# Comma question: Aufgrund des Wetters und da 3 Tage vergangen waren[,] marschierten wir los

Tags: spelling, comma, subordinate-clause

I wouldn’t use a comma in:

> Aufgrund des Wetters marschierten wir los.

I would use a comma in:

> Da drei Tage vergangen waren, marschierten wir los.

But what is the correct punctuation in the following?

> Aufgrund des Wetters und da drei Tage vergangen waren[,] marschierten wir los.

Comment: I'd rather use „wegen“ (“because of”) than „aufgrund“ (“on the basis of”).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would actually write:

> Aufgrund des Wetters, und da drei Tage vergangen waren, marschierten wir los.

but you should wait for another opinion.

The second comma is non-negotiable, and the first one seems to be strongly indicated by the need to make a speech pause to make the awkward parallelism of a prepositional phrase and a sentence intelligible.

Comment: @Takkat: No, it treats the inner phrase as "Einschub".

Comment: The **optional** comma can be set when the "Einschub" is an independent sentence (§73). This is the case here, like saying "Drei Tage waren vergangen" - you are right!

Answer (score 3):

The relevant rule is § 74 E2:

> Wenn eine beiordnende Konjunktion wie *und, oder* (§ 72) Satzglieder oder Teile von Satzgliedern mit Nebensätzen verbindet, so steht zwischen den Bestandteilen einer solchen Reihung kein Komma. Gegenüber dem übergeordneten Satz sind die Teile der Reihung nur dann mit Komma abgetrennt, wenn der Nebensatz anschließt, nicht aber, wenn das Satzglied bzw. ein Teil eines Satzgliedes anschließt:
>   *[…]*
>   *Bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht, ist das Rauchen hier streng verboten.*

So there has to be a comma after *waren* in your example sentence:

> Aufgrund des Wetters und da drei Tage vergangen waren**,** marschierten wir los.

You may regard *und da drei Tage vergangen waren* as parenthesis and thus also put a comma before *und,* but I would consider this not to be appropriate in most contexts.